# webview loadUrl stops working AFTER controls on google forms get the focus

Tags: javascript, android, back-button, google-forms

I was trying to create a kiosk-wrapper for a bunch of *google forms* surveys and thought that maybe that was a good opportunity to get a taste of android development (my first attempt that is).

## the problem

I'm overriding the `onBackPressed()` in order to allow the user to jump to my *homepage* (an index page with links to various surveys) when I realized that once the user had already given focus to some input field on the survey form, I was no longer able to load the homepage (loadUrl).

I couldn't replicate this behavior with the input fields in other sites such as google.com. Therefore my guess is that *google forms* uses some complex javascript(?) and this somehow messes up with subsequent `loadUrl` calls? But it being my first attempt in java or android, I'm ashamed to admit that I'm groping in the dark.

## My code that exhibits the problem

I've trimmed down the code exhibiting the issue to the bare minimum. Both `loadUrl()` calls, open a sample google form that I've created. I'd be so glad if somebody could point out my mistake and give me some lead as to how to overcome this issue!

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected FrameLayout webViewPlaceholder;
    protected WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the UI
        initUI();
    }

    protected void initUI()
    {
        // Retrieve UI elements
        webViewPlaceholder = ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder));

        // Initialize the WebView if necessary
        if (webView == null)
        {
            // Create the webview
            webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


            // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            // Load a page
            webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdkbLwUPSPL1fx1oL8iMyLkBiMY591qjZ-xwCEf15fyX3ikYw/viewform");
        }

        // Attach the WebView to its placeholder
        webViewPlaceholder.addView(webView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdkbLwUPSPL1fx1oL8iMyLkBiMY591qjZ-xwCEf15fyX3ikYw/viewform");
    }
```

## Behavior

As it is, it will load the sample survey form. If you press the android UI back button, it will reload it (for simplicity in this example I use the same url as a homepage). If you navigate forward (2nd step of the survey) the android UI back button will take you to the cover page, indicating that indeed `loadUrl()` worked. But if on the 2nd step you give focus to the text field (or the radio buttons), the android UI back button will stop functioning.

## Errors

Everytime I press the UI back button (regardless of whether it works or not, I get the following error):

```
W/UnimplementedWebViewApi: Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2310)
```

Before stripping down the code to the bare essentials, I'd get the next message instead:

```
Webview loadUrl won't work after user focuses on google forms form controls (error InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient)
```

I've found multiple posts on both error messages, but nothing that I could relate to. Any help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing how a good night's sleep can help! 
For what it's worth, I tried the following and it works now: Before reloading a new url with `loadUrl()` I disable javascript and re-enable it as soon as I load the new page!

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdkbLwUPSPL1fx1oL8iMyLkBiMY591qjZ-xwCEf15fyX3ikYw/viewform");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

The above code is the `onBackPressed()` body